# regex pattern to find word repetition between two specific words

Tags: regex, perl

I am able to find the repetition pattern for a given sentence using `(.+)(?=\1+)`. But when I tried the same between two specific words in a sentence it fails with "no match".

Am I missing something here.

Example:

```
abc def def def def ghi ghi xyz
```

When I use `/abc (.+)(?=\1+) xyz/`, it fails with no match.

Don't want to add first word and second word under any conditional paranthesis. 
So I want the regex statement to be of this type
/abc regex expression def/

Comment: Which two specific words?

Comment: What's the pattern you're using to match specific words?

Comment: I used /abc (.+)(?=\1+) def/ to find the repetition between abc and def

Comment: Ah. Please edit your question to reflect that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In response to your edit, the pattern you first used isn't working because (1) you're not properly accounting for spaces, (2) you're over-specifying where the matched segment must begin and end, and (3) you're not really using the look-ahead feature correctly. Here's a more in-depth explanation:

- by specifying that the pattern is between `abc` and `def`, you are limiting the substrings that can be matched to `def def def`, `def def`, or `def`.
- Presumably, you want to match the first of the above three options to be matched. But note that because your second group is a look-ahead, the first group must match the *entire substring*.
- The lookahead means that the string immediately *after* the lookahead atom is matched by the lookahead atom. So your pattern is indicating that `def` must match `\1+`. But `def` starts with a space, so it can't match any of the aforementioned strings (`def def def`, `def def`, or `def`).

---

What it appears you're *actually* trying to do is specify that the matched segment of the string should be *preceded* by the word `abc` and *followed* by the word `def`. In that case, just use a lookbehind and a lookahead:

```
/(?<=\babc\b).*?(\w+)\W+(\1\b\W*)+.*?(?=\bdef\b)/
```

I got rid of your original lookahead; the match you want (i.e. the word that's repeated) is in the first capture group (i.e. the variable `$1`). Note that I'm using `\w` and `\W` to distinguish between word and non-word characters in addition to the `\b` "word boundary" zero-width atom.

EDIT: The lookahead/lookbehind are actually unnecessary. Since you want to use a pattern without them, here's the version you want:

```
/\babc\b.*?(\w+)\W+(\1\b\W*)+.*?\bdef\b/
```

Comment: i don't know the word def affront. i need to find the word

Comment: @user3605127 .....so why is it in your pattern? I'm having a very hard time understanding exactly what it is you want to do.

Comment: @user3605127 I've edited the second section of my answer to create a pattern that I *think* does what you want, assuming you really want to find the repeating word *between* the words `abc` and `def`.

Comment: If instead you wanted to, say, find the repeating word between `def` and `xyz`, you would change the beginning of the pattern to `(?<=\bdef\b)` and the end to `(?=\bxyz\b)`, and after the match `$1` would be set to the string `ghi`.

Comment: Kyle, Is there a way to find without specifying abc and def words within such conditional paranthesis.

Comment: Find *what*, exactly? Again, I don't know what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry for the incomplete sentence. I want to create the string as /<start_string><expression><end_string>/. For the above example, the string should be /abc <expression> xyz/. I hope this clarifies you my requirement.

Comment: .....no, unfortunately it doesn't. Why are you specifying start and end strings? Are those parts of the input string that you know for sure you (1) don't want to match and (2) surround the part that you *do* want to match?

Comment: @user3605127 Are you saying that my regex pattern does what you want, you just don't want to use the `(?<=...)` and `(?=...)` constructs? In that case, just remove them: `/\babc\b.*?(\w+)\W+(\1\b\W*)+.*?\bdef\b/`.

Comment: See http://regex101.com/r/rH5wF4 and let me know if that's what you're looking for.